# How do I verify the digital signature of an image from the WDM driver?

Tags: windows, driver, digital-signature, wdm

I need to verify the digital signatures of downloaded images (dll, exe), if the image does not have a specific signature, it is necessary to reject its download. How can I do this? Are there functions for verifying digital signatures?
Both a complete answer and partial information on the question will be useful.

Comment: `WinVerifyTrust()`

Comment: WinVerifyTrust() is user space API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **no** public API by Microsoft, you have two options:

1. Use undocumented API - there is [sample here](https://github.com/Ido-Moshe-Github/CiDllDemo)
2. Implement your own test, by reading the image and check signature using [CNG Kernel API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/cng-features#kernel-mode-support) ([BCrypt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/cng-cryptographic-primitive-functions?redirectedfrom=MSDN))